# jquery validation script not resetting when another ajax call is made

Tags: jquery

hey, I'm using a jquery plugin and when i focus in on a field and focus out it alerts me of a validation error.

now in my set up I have a menu that loads content from another page via ajax, and with in that content I have another sub menu that also calls content in with another ajax request.

Scenario

I click on Files from main menu, then click on View from sub menu, then on Create from there (using another ajax request)

on the Create content is where I am using the validation plugin, so like I said when I focus in and out it works, BUT if I click on Files again from the main menu the validation error remain in place where they popped up. If i click on View from the sub menu then the validation error fade out.

I tried to isolate the issue as to why the error fade out with an ajax call from the sub menu but now with the main menu.

Main menu script:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------
// Pidget menu
//------------------------------------------------------------------
var content = '#main-content',
    wrap = '#wrap';
$("nav a.files-menu-link").live('click', function({
    $.validationEngine.closePrompt('.formError',true);
    $(content).hide(200, function(){
        $(wrap).load('files.php' + content, function(){
            $(this).hide().html(data).slideDown(500);
        });
    })
    return false;
});
```

sub menu script

```
$('a#prospect-file-link').live('click', function(){
    $.validationEngine.closePrompt('.formError',true);
    $.post('resources/ajax/ajax.php', {
        action : 'prospects',
        uid    : uid
    }, function(data){
        $('#files-right-pane').hide().html(data).slideDown(500);
        $(".alpha").click(function() {
            $(this).find("span").toggleClass("expand-alpha-down");
            $(this).next(".show").slideToggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

then the create new script

```
//-- Create new prospect
$('a.new-prospect').live('click', function(){
    $('#files-right-pane').fadeOut(200);
    $.post('resources/ajax/ajax.php', {
        action : 'create_prospect',
        uid    : uid
    }, function(data){
        $('#files-right-pane').hide().html(data).slideDown(500);
        selectBox('prospect-type', 'prospect-type-td');
        selectBox('status', 'status-td');
        selectBox('primary-number', 'primary-td');
        selectBox('secondary-number', 'secondary-td');
        mce('new-prospect-comments');
        $("#new-prospect-form").validationEngine();
        $('.state').autoSuggest('resources/ajax/suggest.php', {minChars: 2, matchCase: false, startText: '', asHtmlID: 'state'});
    });
    return false;
});
```

html markup

```
...
<td><input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" class="validate[required]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="middle_name" name="middle_name" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" class="validate[required]" /></td>
...
```

Thats my setup, I can't figure out the .closePromp() works in the view but not with the main menu link

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are missing a parenthesis after 'function('.

Instead of:

```
$("nav a.files-menu-link").live('click', function({
```

it should be:

```
$("nav a.files-menu-link").live('click', function(){
```

Comment: hmmm, i seem to have that already fixed in my code. Must of been a version I copied and pasted before fixing it. Still problem persist tho.